# CPU & Memory steadily increase & FPS drops all because of vector movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

My CPU & Memory steadily increases over the course of roughly 6 minutes during play testing of my current Sprite Kit game. I've found that the method '-(void)walkToward:(CGPoint)targetPosition' inside the Player class is responsible (it moves the character to a tapped location on screen), but I DON'T understand why. The game is orthogonal with no gravity. The Player class is initialized in an SKScene called TesMap. Here is the code inside the Player class:

Player.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "CharacterWalking.h"


@interface Player : CharacterWalking

//Player movement stuff.
@property NSTimeInterval lastUpdateTime; //Keep track of the last time update: was called.
@property NSTimeInterval dt; //Keep track of the Delta Time since the last update.
@property CGPoint velocity; //CGPoints represent positions. However, here it'll represent a 2D vector (direction & length) instead.
@property CGPoint touchLocation; //Where the player will move to.
@property CGPoint lastTouchLocation; //Will keep track of last position.
@property BOOL walking; //Will either stop or begin walking animation.
@property float distance;


-(void)walkToward:(CGPoint)targetPosition;
-(void)faceCurrentDirection;
-(void)GPS:(CFTimeInterval)cT;

@end
```

Player.m

```
-(void)GPS:(NSTimeInterval)cT
{
    //Keeps track of update methods update function: Actual update timing is slightly different/inexact every time.
    if (self.lastUpdateTime)
    {
        _dt = cT - _lastUpdateTime; //Calculate the time since the last call to update: & store it in _dt.
    }
    else
    {
        _dt = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = cT;
    //NSLog(@"%0.2f milliseconds since last update", _dt * 1000); //Log the time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds).


    /*Distance: fundamental for tracking the charatcer's last position*/
    CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(_lastTouchLocation, self.position); //Distance between previous location & current player position.
    _distance = CGPointLength(offset); //Converts CGPoint to CGFloat for the IF statement.

    if (_distance < 50 * _dt)
    {
        _walking = NO;
        self.position = _lastTouchLocation;
        self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
        [self faceCurrentDirection]; //Update texture.
    }
}

-(void)faceCurrentDirection
{
    //Some direction facing code is in here.
}

//THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO HIDE.
-(void)walkToward:(CGPoint)targetPosition
{
    _walking = YES;

    CGPoint targetVector = CGPointNormalize(CGPointSubtract(targetPosition, self.position)); //Gets distance between point A & B.

    targetVector = CGPointMultiplyScalar(targetVector, 50); //50 is interpreted as a speed: the larger the # the faster the player moves.

    //COMMENTED OUT. PLAYER CAN'T MOVE NOW. BUT CPU & MEMORY NOT STEADILY INCREASING... WTF
    //self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(targetVector.x, targetVector.y); //Velocity vector measured in meters per second.

    [self faceCurrentDirection];
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    //BLA BLA BLA
    //JUST SOME CODE HERE THAT SETS UP THE PLAYER CHARACTER.

        _walking = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is how it looks inside the SKScene/map:

TestMap.h

```
//#import some more BLA BLA BLA
#import "Player.h"


@interface TestScene1 : SKScene

//BLA BLA BLA

@property Player *player;

//BLA BLA BLA

@end
```

TestMap.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _player.touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_worldNode];
    _player.lastTouchLocation = _player.touchLocation; //Save the previous position.
    [_player walkToward:_player.touchLocation]; //Tells the player sprite to move toward the location of the user’s tap.
}


-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /*Called before each frame is rendered*/

    [_player GPS:currentTime];
}
```

I can't understand why the 'physicsBody.velocity' within the Player class is influencing the CPU & Memory increase. The game starts at 60 FPS but after roughly 6 minutes the FPS drops to anywhere between 30 to 15. If nobody knows why this is happening, can someone then show me how to properly set up vector movement for my Player class?

Comment: nothing jumps right off. Do you have a github project(assuming you have isolated the problem if you don't want to share all your code)

Comment: Display the node count on your screen and see if that increases as your FPS decrease.

Comment: I'm going to see to the GitHub idea. Regarding displaying node count, well it's always on during development. Unfortunately, it's not increasing (that might have been easier to fix).

Comment: By the way, the maximum node count I get is 36 on the current map I'm testing, yet around that 6 minute mark the phone heats up significantly as if running a very demanding game. I think something in the above code has created a loop [maybe because of (void)update method] & forcing the CPU to endlessly process something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my own problem. During character movement through touch, the SKScene's -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime method runs that characters class method [_player GPS:currentTime]; which tracks speed and distance. Here's the hiccup, that method sets the character texture according to the direction he is facing. Every frame the same texture continues to be placed into the character flooding memory with repetitive textures. All I had to do was put a conditional stop to this texture setting method while the character was standing so that it wouldn't be called every frame but called only once.